# pandas update multiple fields

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add and update multiple columns in a pandas dataframe using a second dataframe. The problem I get is when the number of columns I want to add doesn't match the number of columns in the base dataframe I get the following error: "Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (2, 2)"

A simplified version of the problem is below

```
tst = DataFrame({"One":[1,2],"Two":[2,4]})

def square(row):
    """
    for each row in the table return multiple calculated values
    """
    a = row["One"]
    b = row["Two"]
    return a ** 2, b ** 2, b ** 3

#create three new fields from the data
tst[["One^2", "Two^2", "Two^3"]] = tst.apply(square, axis=1)
```

if the number of fields being added matches the number already in the table the opertaion works as expected.

```
tst = DataFrame({"One":[1,2],"Two":[2,4]})

def square(row):
    """
    for each row in the table return multiple calculated values
    """
    a = row["One"]
    b = row["Two"]
    return a ** 2, b ** 2

#create three new fields from the data
tst[["One^2", "Two^2"]] = tst.apply(square, axis=1)
```

I realise I could do each field seperately but in the actual problem I am trying to solve I perform a join between the table being updated and an external table within the "updater" (i.e. square) and want to be able to grab all the required information at once.

Below is how I would do it in SQL. Unfortunately the two dataframes contain data from different database technologies, hence why I have to do perform the operation in pandas.

```
update  tu
set     tu.a_field = upd.the_field_i_want
        tu.another_field = upd.the_second_required_field
from    to_update tu
        inner join the_updater upd
            on tu.item_id = upd.item_id
            and tu.date between upd.date_from and upd.date_to
```

Here you can see the exact details of what I am trying to do. I have a table "to_update" that contains point-in-time information against an item_id. The other table "the_updater" contains date range information against the item_id. For example a particular item_id may sit with customer_1 from DateA to DateB and with customer_2 between DateB and DateC etc. I want to be able to align information from the table containing the date ranges against the point-in-time table.

Please note a merge won't work due to problems with the data (this is actually being written as part of a dataquality test). I really need to be able to replicate the functionality of the update statement above.

I could obviously do it as a loop but  I was hoping to use the pandas framework where possible.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve here? for squaring the values this is trivial to perform and doesn't require the use of `apply` in this case

Comment: I am trying to create arbitrarily many fields and assign them values simultaneously using the apply method. The simple functions in the example just represent any arbitraryfunction I may want to use for generating a new field. The issue is when trying to create more than 1 field in the above example it errors. Once I can do this I can replace the trivial function with any value.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a empty column in dataframe and assign it to zero

```
 tst["Two^3"] = 0
```

Then do the respective operations for that column, along with other columns

```
 tst[["One^2", "Two^2", "Two^3"]] = tst.apply(square, axis=1)
```

Try printing it

```
 print tst.head(5)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that fixes the issue. However if I then set my square function to reply a third value I get a similar error but with the dimension values incremented. 'tst = DataFrame({"One":[1,2],"Two":[2,4]})

def square(row):
    """
    for each row in the table return multiple calculated values
    """
    a = row["One"]
    b = row["Two"]
    return a ** 2, b ** 2, b ** 3, b ** 4

tst["Two^3"] = 0
tst[["One^2", "Two^2", "Two^3", "Two^4"]] = tst.apply(square, axis=1)
tst' Do you know what is going on under the hood?

Comment: Try writing this tst["Two^3"] = 0 in a for loop, so that columns are dynamically created, like ["Two^3"], ["Two^4"] in a loop and assigned to zero.

Comment: This will certainly fix the problem. But it will involve having the apply return only a single field at once. What I was curious about was being able to use apply to return arbritrarily many fields. By being able to do this it should allow for cleaner code.